# Ошибка в Google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

google colab выдает ошибку "Подключение к среде выполнения "Серверный ускоритель Python 3 на базе Google Compute Engine ()."…

Вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я хотел сделать: изменить версию python с 3.10 на python 3.8 для установки пакета с зависимостями для TIM-net нейронной сети. Но то эта ошибка не даёт выполнять команды, хотя один раз у меня как-то получилось ввести команду (см. ниже). В итоге, я думаю, нужно что-то сделать с ядром colab, но я не знаю что.

Вот что я делал, что в конечном итоге привило к этому:

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

```
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
```

После чего оно появилось и я это исправил командой:

```
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Команды выше я взял отсюда: ["Пошаговая инструкция как изменить версию python в google colab"](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/python/change-python-version-in-google-colab-steps/):

Потом я решил установить pip, используя модуль get-pip.py

```
!python get-pip.py
```

Но получил:

```
2 сек.
!python /content/TIM-net/get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/TIM-net/get-pip.py", line 33036, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/TIM-net/get-pip.py", line 135, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "/content/TIM-net/get-pip.py", line 111, in bootstrap
    monkeypatch_for_cert(tmpdir)
  File "/content/TIM-net/get-pip.py", line 92, in monkeypatch_for_cert
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/tmp/tmpeh0txkaq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

И решил ошибку:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils
```

Команду взял отсюда:

```
https://itsourcecode.com/modulenotfounderror/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils-cmd-solved/#:~:text=The%20modulenotfounderror%20no%20module%20named,you%20will%20get%20the%20ModuleNotFoundError
```

После чего я снова попытался установить pip и он установился, далее запустил:

```
!pip install -r /content/TIM-net/requirement.txt
```

Содержимое файла requirement.txt:

```
cvxopt==1.3.0
h5py==3.1.0
keras==2.7.0
librosa==0.9.2
matplotlib==3.6.1
numba==0.56.3
numpy==1.19.5
openpyxl==3.0.10
pandas==1.3.0
prettytable==3.4.1
scikit-learn==1.1.2
scipy==1.9.2
spafe==0.2.0
speechpy==2.4
tensorflow-gpu==2.7.0
tqdm==4.63.1
```

Это лишь зависимости проекта TIM-net:

```
https://github.com/Jiaxin-Ye/TIM-Net_SER/tree/main
```

После я установил все зависимости и сделал решил исправить ошибку с protobuf для своего python3.8:

```
!pip uninstall protobuf==3.20.*
```

После чего google colab попросил перезапустить среду, я это и сделал, в итоге эта история приключилась! И это фигня происходит лишь когда презапускаешь сеанс.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Я заметил, что такая ошибка может возникнуть в любой момент практически при изменении того или иного параметра среды, мне помогло лишь игнорировать сообщения с просьбой перезагрузить по причине того что среда была изменена. Просто не перезапускайте сеанс!

Comment: Собственно, это не ошибка, это сообщение, на котором он, видимо, зависает.